# lighttpd coredump when it start. Find 6w+ core file in server. It likes closed loop coredump

Tags: lighttpd

Coredump info：

```
(gdb) bt

#0  0x0000000000004296 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fc6d7bb898d in mod_proxy_trigger (srv=0x58a0d0, p_d=Variable "p_d" is not available.
) at mod_proxy_core.c:3140
#2  0x0000000000428a55 in plugins_call_handle_trigger (srv=0x58a0d0) at plugin.c:430
#3  0x00000000004156af in main (argc=Variable "argc" is not available.
) at server.c:636
```

It Can not be reproduced.

The lighttpd's version is `lighttpd-1.5.0.1600`

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking for help with. Can you expand?

Comment: 1. 首先我们现在没法复现，在部署环境的时候core掉的，而且是死循环的core，10分钟内core了6万多次，当发现问题把lighttpd停掉后，再启动就无法复现了 2.分析core，发现最低层的栈是看不到的，从目前的core信息分析不出是什么原因，所以想看看是否有人碰到过这样的问题？